# Embedded template channel entries tag inexplicably breaking in some host templates

Tags: channel-entries, templates, embeds

I've got an embedded template called _sidebar that contains (surprise surprise) the site's sidebar content. It contains a heading and a channel:entries tag, all wrapped in a container div. In some templates (eg. the index template of the 'news' template group) the C:E tag works as expected. However, when I embed _sidebar into the news/view template *and access a particular news article via a {url_title_path} link* the C:E tag fails to generate any content.

However, I can see that _sidebar *is* getting embedded, because the heading and the container div appear in the sidebar region as expected. It's just that none of the content that should be called in by the C:E tag is there.

Both the 'news' and 'news/view' host templates have identical structures. There are no nested C:E tags either in the host template or in the embedded template. If I go to the URL domain.com/news/view (without selecting a specific article) then the sidebar displays correctly. It is only when the same template is used for a specific article (e.g.. domain.com/news/view/my-article-title that the glitch occurs.

BTW, I have no conditionals relating to segment_3 in my templates. There are some conditionals acting on the value of segment_1 in the _sidebar template, but if they were being triggered then the heading and container div would be removed from the template also.

I'm a bit stumped. Without getting into the whole template code (yet) does anyone have any immediate thoughts, or has anyone run across this phenomena?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Semi-educated guess: You need to set `dynamic="no"` on the channel entries tag. If that's not the issue then I'd suggest posting some template code so that people can see what's going on.

Comment: Oh my god. I can’t believe that I fell over the old Dynamic="no" step. That was it. Thanks. _Puts rookie hat back on_

Comment: Ha, no worries. We've all done it at some point.